# How to render 3D words without lighting?

Tags: light

Some person made a 3D intro video and his render has lighting affects but I don't see the light source in that file.
I was wondering is there a way to light up an object without like UV shape emitting light?

Here is a [drop box](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uoa8t50r8n02gn/AAAxScAHcXKKv0xlQhOzijDEa?dl=0) link to the intro file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a link only question. Please try to explain your problem, with text and images. Blend files are great, but can not be the main part of the question.

Comment: Good edit Jon. I retracted my DV. Now (in my opinion) you have a good question.

Comment: Under Shading in the material for the text, select Shadeless, and check if that is the effect you're missing. It was turned on in the template file but turned off in the Intro V3 file.

Comment: Duane Dibbley that did it Thank you know i know how to make a matte look thank you